# Compiling C# .Net from Command Line

Tags: c#-4.0, msbuild, nuget

I'm trying to compile a c# .net project only using command line so that I could create a bat file to compile and run the Selenium tests. I exported the code from SVN. And I opened the command prompt and am able to restore packages using below command.

And then when I try to compile with msbuild it could not reference the dll added in through the nuget. I know in visual studio through package manager console I can use a command (update -reinstall) and make it work, but how to do this without visual studio.

```
==== bat file ======
REM Restore External Pacakages
nuget restore packages.config -PacakgesDirectory D:\Testproject\packages"
msbuid TestProject.sln
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to reference **Msbuild** executable

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
```

OR

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
```

then you need to pass the `.sln` or `.csproj` file path (depends on your working folder) as parameter.

You can also specify the msbuild's targets ex. **Clean**, **Rebuild**, **Build** => As they exists in Visual Studio.

The final command could look like this:

**Template**:

```
{.NetFrameworkPath}\msbuild.exe {pathToSln} /t:{Build,Clean,Rebuild}
```

**Examples**

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe TestProject.sln /t:Build

C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe TestProject.sln /t:Clean;Build
```

Comment: Yes, am doing the same. The issue I have is that I restored packages through nuget (in command prompt outside visual studio). And these dlls are not referenced when I compile and it givens an error "type or namespace name could not be found.."

Comment: Just follow the command 
`D:\projects\contoso\> nuget.exe restore contoso.sln`
ref from [Nuget Docs](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore)

Comment: You can also edit your .sln file and there's boolean that says if you want to restore nuget packages while building.