# Coded UI compile and generate DLL from cmd

Tags: c#, .net, automation, coded-ui-tests

I am creating a Coded UI Test (C#) (via Hand Coding), so as to automate a .NET application.

I wanted to know is there a way to compile and generate the DLLs for the Coded UI test using the command line.

Thanks in advance !!!

Regards,

Kallol Ghose

Comment: Depending on your IDE, you should be able to use that. For VS, [this would be a way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36093175/compiling-c-sharp-net-from-command-line).

Comment: Thanks @nondestructive it worked for me !!